# Troubleshooting Facebook's graph.put_object that returns error 400

Tags: python, google-app-engine, facebook-graph-api, urllib2

I am using Facebook Python's SDK along with Google App Engine, and making a call to do a checkin:

```
graph.put_object("me", "checkins", message="Hello, world", place="165039136840558", coordinates='{"latitude":"38.2454064", "longitude":"-122.0434404"}')
```

However, this throws an error 400 Bad Request and I don't seem to be able to try catch it so I can have the important information.

On a bad request, Facebook should return, an object like below which can help troubleshoot and address the issue, but I am not sure how I can retrieve this object:

```
{
   "error": {
    "type" : "OAuthException",
    "message" : "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user."
    }
   }
```

[Edit]

I am temporarily able to figure out the issue by:
Logging the Post Data

```
logging.info("LOG" + str(post_data))
```

and then using a REST client like the extension for Firefox to make the request again. The response gives me the information I need to proceed. However, it would have been better if I can obtain the error messages within my app.

Answer (score 2):

Like the error says, you need to create and consume an access token:
Here's some more info. Sorry I can't "comment" yet and am forced to answer.
http://benbiddington.wordpress.com/2010/04/23/facebook-graph-api-getting-access-tokens/

Comment: Thanks for the answer Kyle, actually that is one of the many messages that can come back, however I am unsure how I can obtain this message when calling "graph.put_object"

Answer (score 1):

I came across the same issue, and here is how to get that error message:

```
import urllib2

url='https://graph.facebook.com/me/?method=post' # this will 400 b/c it has no auth token.

try:
   resp = urllib2.urlopen(url)
except urllib2.HTTPError as e:
   error_reason = e.read()
```

Then you can use the `json` module to examine the JSON Facebook sends with an error:

```
json_error = json.loads(error_reason)
```

Make sure you use `json.loads`, since `error_reason` is a string